# Thymeleaf Page Fragment to Divide Body

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to divide my page into three parts using thymeleaf fragments/layouts.
Lets say I have following **page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Demo Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="content">Some content goes here</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I am trying to divide it into following three fragments.

**top.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Demo Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
```

**bottom.html**

```
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**page-content.html**

```
<div class="content">Some content goes here</div>
```

I DID TRY AS BELLOW BUT DID NOT WORK:

**top.html**

```
<div th:fragment="top">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Demo Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
</div>
```

**page-content.html**

```
<div th:replace="/top :: top"></div>
<div class="content">Some content goes here</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest me possible direction to look into.

Comment: Did you again try it using `th:insert` ?

Comment: No I did not. Actually `th:insert` keeps the parent `tag` which is not intended.

Comment: You should look into use thymeleaf-layout-dialect instead of what you are doing...

Comment: @Metroids Thanks, for the suggestion. I looked into `thymeleaf-layout-dialect` and it seems very good at layout template. I would like to know if I can achieve the structure above by anything?